# Perforce Rally Integration - Execution failure with Formatted Text

Tags: java, html, integration, perforce, rally

I am looking for a little troubleshooting assistance on this one.

We have a custom integration written in Java that pulls information out of Rally (Artifact type, ID, state, owner, project and some other custom data) and drops it into a Perforce job.  We use this to verify that things are approved/reviewed before we move code around.

So the integration has been up and running for about 6 months and is working great and two days ago it starts failing...but it only fails when the Rally Task in question has html formatting in the description field...the error it produces is:

`ERROR: Error: Job Loader Script [/p4/1/tmp/P4Rally.prod/TA14875.sh] did not run.`

When all formatting is removed from the description field the integration works and runs just like it is supposed to.

We have not updated the java files for the integration in probably 6 weeks.  Our Perforce install has not been updated/changed.  Perforce resides on a Linux machine and I verified we haven't made any changes to the machine itself.  Rally is hosted and I have a question out to their support team to see if anything has changed on the data management/formatting/anything side for them.

I am out of ideas for what could cause this issue.  Any suggestions for threads to follow?

Comment: What is the origin of the text in the Description field of Rally Tasks? Is description entered directly in Rally or copied/pasted from a 3rd party text editor?

Comment: Generally it is either directly edited or copied/pasted from email/word.

Comment: Does it fail in both cases? Would you be able to verify if it fails when it is directly entered in Rally or it fails only when it is copied from MS Word or, perhaps Outlook?

Comment: Yes both options cause a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to identify the source of this issue.  No idea what caused it but we were able to resolve the problem with a form-in trigger/script that cleaned up the formatting.